# Fully replacing app that has been submitted to the apple app store

Tags: ios

My client wants to update his iphone app but he doesn't have access to the source code. Is it possible to update the already existing app by building it from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you just need to use the same bundle ID in your app and maintain the versioning (just make it higher than what it is in the app store). So long as you have the developer account that published the app, then you will be fine

Comment: If we don't have access to the dev account that summited the app, is there a way that we can take over with a new account, by transferring the app licence from the initial dev account to ours? Are there any links that I can do some further reading?
Thanks!

Comment: hmm im not sure, might have to contact apple about that, maybe they just have to delete the app on their side then it would free up the bundle ID, but i dont know if its that simple

Answer (score 1):

Your client can update the existing app if he has the access to the store. Else, while building the new application, he has to maintain the package identifier with higher app version and the rest will be no problem as far as the practice is going on.