# Appstore - How to update an app with a new Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an running app on the Appstore but and i wish to create a newer version of the app. The only thing i want to know is it possible to create a totally new Xcode project and submit it as a new version in the Appstore? if yes what are the steps needed to achieve such a goal without going through any problems.

Comment: seems like you are quite new to iOS Development :)

Comment: Yes it's possible. Only thing you need to do is use the same bundle indentifier.

Comment: thanks guys appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the bundle identifier same, increase the version code! Answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36713455/3921490)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same bundle identifier and increase version of your build and upload it.

Hope it helps.